# Why is Space Patrol Luluco split into "seasons"?

Tags: space-patrol-luluco

So far, every three-episode block of Space Patrol Luluco has been demarcated as a "season" according to messages that pop up on screen at the end of the third episode.

Here's the last scene of Episode 3:

[image: Episode 3]

Here's the last scene of Episode 6:

[image: Episode 6]

Here's the first scene of Episode 7:

[image: Episode 7]

Why is this? There wasn't any break in production or airing between these blocks, was there? Is it just for style, an affectionate reference to long-running shows?

Comment: There's no real break, but each "season" does cover a single story arc.